# Is it safe to create my own SDL Event struct?

Tags: c++, sdl

I would like to use SDL User Events to track custom events in my application. My problem is that the SDL_UserEvent structure only provides one int and two void pointers.

```
typedef struct{
  Uint8 type;
  int code;
  void *data1;
  void *data2;
} SDL_UserEvent;
```

I would prefer to have an event with the following structure:

```
typedef struct{
  Uint8 type; /* Set to SDL_USEREVENT + MAP */
  int   code; /* Set to MAP_COLLISION */
  Uint8 tile_x;
  Uint8 tile_y;
  Uint8 tile_type;
} UserEvent_MapCollision;
```

I could then reinterpret_cast the struct whenever I want to handle MAP events, and throw away the message without additional processing if I don't. My event handlers would be simplified using this technique (no need to malloc and free this struct and attach it to the event).

As long as I check (at build time?) that `sizeof(UserEvent_MapCollision) <= sizeof(SDL_Event)`, and the SDL event queue doesn't modify a pushed event in any way, will this work?

Comment: ... or use a better event class. http://drrobsjournal.blogspot.co.uk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will work, remember that the `SDL_Event` struct itself is a big `union`. You are correct, if you are unsure your struct will fit into an `SDL_Event` you can add this compile time assert: `sizeof(UserEvent_MapCollision) <= sizeof(SDL_Event)`.

```
/* Push event */
SDL_Event e;
UserEvent_MapCollision* p = static_cast<UserEvent_MapCollision*>(&e);;

e.type = SDL_USEREVENT + MAP;
e.code = MAP_COLLISION;
p.tile_x = 10;
p.tile_y = 20;
p.tile_type = 7;

/* Receive event */
SDL_Event e;
while (SDL_PollEvents(&e)) {
    if (e.type == SDL_USEREVENT + MAP) {
        if (e.user.code == MAP_COLLISION) {
            UserEvent_MapCollision *p = static_cast<UserEvent_MapCollision>(&e)
            HandleMapCollision(p);
        }
    }
}
```

To check at compile time the assertion you can use the SDL macro `SDL_COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT`, it is defined in `SDL_stdinc.h`:

```
SDL_COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(UserEvent_MapCollision, sizeof(UserEvent_MapCollision) <= sizeof(SDL_Event));
```

As a side note, those two `void*` pointers are intended to reference another structure.

```
typedef struct {
  Uint8 tile_x;
  Uint8 tile_y;
  Uint8 tile_type;
} MyCustomEventStruct;

/* Create event */

SDL_UserEvent e;
MyCustomEventStruct *p;

p = new MyCustomEventStruct;
p->tile_x = 10;
p->tile_y = 20;
p->tile_type = 7;

e.type = SDL_USEREVENT + MAP;
e.code = MAP_COLLISION;
e.data1 = p;
e.data2 = 0;

SDL_PushEvent(&e);

/* Receive Event */

while (SDL_PollEvents(&e)) {
    if (e.type == SDL_USEREVENT + MAP) {
        if (e.user.code == MAP_COLLISION) {
            MyCustomEventStruct* p = static_cast<MyCustomEventStruct*>(e.user.data1);
            HandleMapCollision(p);
            delete p;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP knows this but is looking to avoid it if possible:  "no need to malloc and free this struct and attach it to the event"

Comment: @vz0 do you know how to check that sizeof(UserEvent_MapCollision) <= sizeof(SDL_Event) at compile time?

Comment: @Martin: `boost::static_assert` or conditional template metaprogramming that creates `int array[-1];` if condition isn't met.

Answer (score 1):

While that might work, I think you would be better off doing something like this in a function or a macro:

```
Uint8 tile_x = static_cast<Uint8>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(sdl_event->data1) & 0xFF);
Uint8 tile_y = static_cast<Uint8>((reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(sdl_event->data1) >> 8) & 0xFF);
Uint8 tile_type = static_cast<Uint8>((reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(sdl_event->data1) >> 16) & 0xFF);
```

and this:

```
sdl_event->data1 = reinterpret_cast<void *>(
    static_cast<uintptr_t>(tile_x) |
    static_cast<uintptr_t>(tile_y) << 8 |
    static_cast<uintptr_t>(tile_type) << 16 );
```